# Retrieve browser history records in all the browser apps in android?

Tags: android, browser, android-browser

I want to get all the browser history records from different browsers in android mobile phone ?(Maybe as you know, there are usually more than one browser apps in a phone ).Is there anyone has done this successfully and give me a hint ? Example code is preferred.Any help will be helpful.. Thanks a lot in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at this. I used it in my code and I am getting browser history through it(Default Browser).

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
    String selection = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
    mCursor = this.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, selection, null, null);
    this.startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();

    String title = "";
    String url = "";

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst() && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {

            title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            url = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            // Do something with title and url

            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

**Limitations :**

`Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` will, at most, work for the open source Browser app that is part of the Android Open Source Project. Device manufacturers are welcome to replace that app with something else that will not be recording its history, bookmarks, or anything else in that `ContentProvider`. Similarly, users are allowed to download third-party browsers, which may not be storing things in that `ContentProvider`.

Comment: @ashu Check my answer and notify me whether this helpful to you or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is for default browser in android.i need history of all browsers in android.